# How to give access to custom created PHP pages inside Joomla 3.4.1 folder

Tags: .htaccess, joomla3.0

My Joomla is installed inside sub folder called "arc" of my main website  (http://www.example.com/arc).

I added a custom PHP page called **reg_process.php** inside the folder named "registration" under Joomla (arc) folder. But I'm having Forbidden access error when I access http://www.example.com/arc/registration/reg_process.php

[image]
Please help me.

Thank you,

Comment: Please show us your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Sorry. It is too long that I can't show here as comment. Here's the Google Drive link to that.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HCVdl1aCj4ebJd1vp1BpWG7CLdNjpF2UIPgnIGdek0c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Den, you can always [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30951157/edit) your post and add the `.htaccess` file there (there is an edit link under it).

Comment: @Lfurini, do you mean to paste all the codes here?